# List in multiple columns

Tags: html, css

I have one list with 10 (li) elements. Those are displayed in single column.

If I fixed height of that list then how can I display it in two or three columns?

Comment: Here's a live example of how to do it in jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/EebVF/5 Using this jquery plugin: http://github.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a CSS3 solution for that, but it's not widely implemented by browsers yet. See this example, using the CSS property `column-count`:

http://jsfiddle.net/hwzpy/

Currently only works in FF, Safari and Chrome though. Otherwise, you'll have to use javascript or divide the list up in two lists.

-edit-
The float variant as linked in other answers is really neat, didn't know about that one.

Comment: It should be column-count, not list-count

Comment: you're right, strange how that went unnoticed for so long. fixed!

Answer (score 4):

you can check this [multiple column lists](http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists)

Comment: The link is broken link :(

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before. See discussion on [html css - how to create multiple column list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347060/html-css-how-to-create-multiple-column-list). There is also a helpful [A List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/) that covers six methods for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this really easily with the [jQuery-Columns Plugin](http://github.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns) for example to split a ul with a class of .mylist into 5 columns you would do

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('.mylist').cols(5);
});
```

Here's a [live example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EebVF/5)