# 2 row element layout within horizontal div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put together a small thumbnail gallery and have run into a slight snag. Structure is very basic and is as follows:

[parent container]
[x number of child elements]
[/parent container]

I want my child elements to load into the parent container like so:

example 1
[0][2][4][6][8]
[1][3][5][7][9]

What I want to know is if there is a pure CSS solution to this or if I'll have to position my elements with javascript.

Knowing that the browser wants to load the items in like this

example2
[0][1][2][3][4]
[5][6][7][8][9]

I'm pretty sure that there isn't a non-javascript way of achieving this but I wanted to ask if anyone had any ideas or experience with this kind of layout.

The ultimate goal is to accomplish 2 things:
1. Have the parent container grow horizontally as new elements are added to it.
2. Keep the 2 row layout as described in example 1.

Comment: How are the thumbnails being pulled in? Is the content static?

Comment: Brodie, take a look at the update in my answer, it may be interesting for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**See update below**

I think I came to a pure CSS3 solution, involving 3d transformation: you can look a **webkit only** demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7fUxz/

basically, the idea behind this demo is starting from a basic element displacement, floating both wrapper and children elements - I used `<ul><li>` for the sake of simplicity and made a `clear:left` starting form `li:nth-child(2n+1)` -  in this way:

```
[0][1]
[2][3]
[4][5]
[6]...
```

then I rotateZ the `ul` so that the whole list is rotated by -90deg and then repositioned with translateX/Y for the right alignment.

But also list items will be rotated: so an inverse Z-rotation is applied to every `<li>`. Another rotation of `180deg` along X-axis is also necessary to give list-items the correct order. Even in this case some adjustments with X|Y translation is needed

The result is

```
[0][2][4][6][8]
[1][3][5][7]...
```

In 3rd revision of the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7fUxz/3/ you can see how to adjust some properties on the list so that the elements before and after are correctly positioned.

Note: this demo is working only on webkit. For a list of browser supporting 3D-transforms look at http://caniuse.com/transforms3d

**Update**

I've done further experiment: if you apply a `float:right` (instead of `float:left`) to each `<li>` 3D Transformations are no longer needed (because elements are already in the right order by row when `<ul>` is rotated) and the css rules are greatly simplified

```
[1][0]
[3][2]
[5][4]
...[6]
```

so this fork

http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/2BDxE/

has an increased support (surprisingly even more respect CSS3 `*-columns` usage), since it works even on Firefox 3.5, Opera 10.5 and probably MSIE 9 (I haven't tested this) : http://caniuse.com/transforms2d .

For older IE consider to serve an alternative style (via conditional comments) or some kind of js/activeX effect using [Matrix Filter](http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/element-rotation-ie-matrix-filter?blog=2)

Comment: I ended up using a different direction to achieve the same result, but this is pretty awesome. Way to think outside the box man.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much of how the information is being pulled in, there is a pure-CSS way using CSS3 multi-columns. BUt, it's CSS3 and the multi-column module only works with the latest version of Firefox and Webkit browsers; as far as I know IE9 still does not support it.

You can read more about CSS3 multi-columns via the following links and how to use them properly.

- http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/
- http://kmsm.ca/2010/an-almost-complete-guide-to-css3-multi-column-layouts/

There is also a column script that I've used once before, though a bit old, may help you.
http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/

Hope this helps!