# Ordering items vertically, and scroll div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have some `div`s, and I want them to start filling the main `div` vertically, and then cause the main `div` to scroll horizontally.

Currently, I'm using `float:left` on child `div`s, but it does exactly the opposite: it starts filling the main `div` horizontally, and then the main div scrolls vertically.

**The number of rows may differ based on screen size**, so I can't create a table for this purpose.

table + some javascript hacks may allow me to do this, but I prefer a CSS (without any javascript) way. Because this code will run on mobile apps, and javascript will slow down the web app.

[This is my current code](http://jsfiddle.net/w6Lf6ah1/), and [here's the result of my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e07Vk.png). But I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtwPb.png).

---

**UPDATE:** As @goliney suggested, seems that it can be done with `css-columns`. I created [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/w6Lf6ah1/1) right now.

Now, there are these two problems:

- While it's working good, it still needs some javascript to determinate number of visible columns (column-count) in the page. Although it's a minor javascript process, is there any way to do it in CSS, too?
- Also, I prefer to show a little bit of fifth column, so user can know that this list is scrollable horizontally. But `columns-count` can't accept some float value (like `4.2`), it only accepts integer values. So how can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at [css3 columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: @goliney Thanks. I created this example right now: http://jsfiddle.net/w6Lf6ah1/1/ While it's working good, it still needs some javascript to determinate number of visible columns (`column-count`) in the page. Although it's a minor javascript process, is there any way to do it in CSS, too?

Comment: try to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705323/2-row-element-layout-within-horizontal-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @goliney suggested, css3 columns can help.

I've created an example of using css3 columns in this issue, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w6Lf6ah1/1).

However, it needs javascript to figure out count of columns, or since I'm targeting tablets, I can create some predefined classes using media queries.

Second, I needed some way to show a little bit of next column, so user can know that this list can be scrolled horizontally.

I've found that if I set a `margin-left` and then take it back into it's right place using `translateX`, it'll happen correctly.

So this is the final code for container `div`:

```
.main {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 40px;

    height:480px;

    margin-left:80px;
    transform: translateX(-80px);
}
```

(I removed prefixed properties here, but they're available in jsFiddle)

And this is the [final result in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6Lf6ah1/6/).