# html - ordered list in multiple columns with page breaks

Tags: html, css

I want to display an order list in a three column layout as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347060/html-css-how-to-create-multiple-column-list) but I'd like to respect the page breaks so that the next element in the list on the second page returns to the top of the first column.

```
p1
1.           4.           7.
2.           5.           8.
3.           6.           9.

p2
10.          12.          14.
11.          13.          15.
```

Comment: what is your html? What is page?

Comment: Is this something like what you are looking for? http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/

Its not cross browser capable though

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "page" and "page break"? I am assuming that your webpage is somehow "paginated" - but you'll need to be more specific as to what you mean...

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have 18 items on your order list. Do you want to display 9 items per a page and when you click a button you want it to display 10th to 18th items? If that's the case and if your page will be asp or jsp or php, you can use data paging methods. For a sample view, you can check this page : https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes&pagesize=15

But if your page will be plain old html page, i suggest you to work some jQuery :)

Comment: That link doesn't go anywhere useful